# IndexError: index 686 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 400

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, python-3.7

Looking to train a model on data that I have collected, however, and IndexError constantly pops up. I've tried using different models or rebuilding the model. Not sure if this is a numpy array error but im pretty sure it's to do with something when I do model.fit().

current training and validation split is
Training samples: 1200
Validation samples: 300

If that helps at all

```
IndexError: index 686 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 400
```

The index error is different on each run

```
IndexError: index 1157 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 400
IndexError: index 486 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 400
```

full error

```
Exception in thread Thread-8:
Traceback (most recent call last):
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\tflearn\data_flow.py", line 187, in fill_feed_dict_queue
    data = self.retrieve_data(batch_ids)
  File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\tflearn\data_flow.py", line 222, in retrieve_data
    utils.slice_array(self.feed_dict[key], batch_ids)
  File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\tflearn\utils.py", line 204, in slice_array
    return X[start]
IndexError: index 486 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 400
Training samples: 1200

Validation samples: 300
```

code:

```
# train_model.py

import numpy as np
from models import alexnet
WIDTH = 160
HEIGHT = 120
LR = 1e-3
EPOCHS = 10
MODEL_NAME = 'F1-{}-{}-{}.model'.format(LR, 'alexnet',EPOCHS)

model = alexnet(WIDTH, HEIGHT, LR)

hm_data = 22
for i in range(EPOCHS):
    for i in range(1,hm_data):
        train_data = np.load('D:/Honors/F1/trainingData/training_data-{}.npy'.format(i), allow_pickle=True)

        train = train_data[:-100]
        test = train_data[-100:]
        
        X = np.array([i[0] for i in train]).reshape(-1,WIDTH,HEIGHT,1)
        Y = [i[1] for i in train]

        test_x = np.array([i[0] for i in test]).reshape(-1,WIDTH,HEIGHT,1)
        test_y = [i[1] for i in test]

        model.fit({'input': X}, {'targets': Y}, n_epoch=1, validation_set=({'input': test_x}, {'targets': test_y}), 
            snapshot_step=500, show_metric=True, run_id=MODEL_NAME)


        model.save(MODEL_NAME)



# tensorboard --logdir=foo:C:/path/to/log
```

Comment: Please show enough traceback to allow identifying where the problem occurs.

Comment: yea, have done. hope it helps, should mention that sometimes the thread error can be thread 7 or some other thread

Comment: Not really. It's still unclear which line of code causes exception.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot re-run the code, cause I don't know what `models` is. I have general suggestion: having inner loop with the same index as outer loop is not a good idea:

```py
for i in range(EPOCHS):
    for i in range(1,hm_data):
        ...
```